# PHP String Replace at the end of a string

Tags: php

I have a long string `Quick brown fox jumped over..... Friends`. I need to replace the string `S` in `Friends` to an empty string so it will finally display as `Friend`.

How can i do this ? `str_replace` will basically do it, but how do i get the last character chopped off ?

Comment: This question misses important details. What is the problem with `str_replace`? And what output would you expect for `sas` or `absd`?

Comment: If you just want to chop off the last character, ever: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php (see the bit about negative length).

Comment: do you just want to lose the last character in your string or do you have other requirements?

Comment: @FlyingMolga `array_pop()` works with arrays, not strings. Clue's in the name ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks... I thought a string might work as a char array, but I must be mixing languages...

Comment: Will `array_pop` remove the last item of an array ? and not the last character of the string ? Can someone show me an example using array_pop ?

Comment: @FlyingMolga No PHP doesn't deal in char arrays unless you explicitly create them (e.g. `str_split()`). The main reason for this is that PHP arrays are huge underneath in terms of the amount of memory they consume vs the amount of data they hold. [Interesting reading on the subject](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html).

Comment: @sharonHwk `$array = str_split($str); array_pop($array); $str = implode('', $array);` - but this is a much less efficient way of doing than `substr($str, 0, -1);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you know what characters you want to remove, use `rtrim`:

```
$str = rtrim($str, "s");
```

In this example we will remove the last character if and only if it is `s` (you can specify a list of characters in the string).

When you just want to remove any last character, use substr:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
```

Comment: Only works is you know that the last character is an `s`, and the string ends with exactly 1 of them.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is exactly what we need to do, isn't it?

Comment: In the given example yes, but the example string is likely arbitrary and the actual problem is "how to remove the last character of *a* string". Although I admit the question is not very clear on that point...

Comment: @DaveRandom: Ok, Dave, probably you I right. I don't know exactly what Saron means. I wilk substr solution also. Thank you!

Comment: use **mb_substr** / **mb_strlen** so it works for most characters, not just english alphabet.... they're available since PHP4.... 4! ....it's PHP8.2 now ......

Answer (score 6):

use substr:

```
$str= substr($str, 0, -1);
```

Comment: Finally someone who knows how `substr()` works. +1

Comment: note that this is a subset of `mb_substr($str, 0, -mb_strlen($stringToReplace)` (note the `-`: this code replaces ANY string at the end of the `$str` + it's multibyte safe

Answer (score 3):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$message = substr($message, 0, -1);
```

Comment: What? Where did 1024 come from? Why not -1?

Answer (score 0):

why not just remove the last character:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str)-1);
```

Comment: nice to see so many different approaches to the same simple problem!

Comment: This would capture the last character, not remove it...

Comment: yeps, forgot the zero :) ---fixing